# Overwriting(extending) default classes?

Tags: python, class, extend, built-in

I would like to be able to overwrite default class when creating a new object of `int`/`set`/`str`/`dict`/etc.

Example for `int`s:

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __call__(self):
        return self ** 2

int = MyInt

a = int('2')
b = 3
print(a)
print(a())
print(int(3)())

print(5()) # Error -> this is what interests me to get working.
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Surely possible with AST, dunno about the rest.

Comment: Just 5 will always have buildin type `int`. When you write `int = MyInt` you do not replace buildin `int`. You just create local var.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must read again some `Python` conventions for identifiers.

**Python Identifiers:**

A Python identifier is a name used to identify a variable, function, class, module or other object. An identifier starts with a letter A to Z or a to z or an underscore (_) followed by zero or more letters, underscores and digits (0 to 9).

Python does not allow punctuation characters such as @, $, and % within identifiers. Python is a case sensitive programming language. Thus, Manpower and manpower are two different identifiers in Python.

Here are naming conventions for Python identifiers:

- Class names start with an uppercase letter. All other identifiers start with a lowercase letter.
- Starting an identifier with a single leading underscore indicates that the identifier is private.
- Starting an identifier with two leading underscores indicates a strongly private identifier.
- If the identifier also ends with two trailing underscores, the identifier is a language-defined special name.

So, you code will fail with `5()` because it dosn't fill with `Python` naming/identifiers rules.

Otherwise, you can hack your code into something like this:

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __call__(self):
        return self ** 2

int = MyInt
a = int('2')
print(a)
print(a())
print(int(3)())
# Note here the underscore '_'
_5 = int('3')
print(_5)
print(_5())
```

Output:

```
2
4
9
3
9
```

Comment: Just another example: `a = 5; a.real` works. `5.real` doesn't

Comment: Yes because `5` will be always a builtin type `int`. So the interpreter will not understand `5.real` and will throw an `SyntaxError` exception.

Comment: Sorry for confusing comment. `5.real` doesn't work because syntax analyzer waits for decimal part after the dot. `(5).real` and `5.0.real` work.